# Warning: mysql_ num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in ...

Tags: php

Пишет, что в 19 строке какая-то ошибка. PHP не знаю совсем. :( **Warning: mysql_ num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in .....hjurl.php on line 19**

```
    <?php /* lilurl.php ( lilURL class file ) */

class lilURL
{
    // constructor
    function lilURL()
    {
        // open mysql connection
        mysql_connect(localhost, LOGIN, PASS) or die('Could not connect to database');
        mysql_select_db(mladsh_linx) or die('Could not select database');   
    }

    // return the id for a given url (or -1 if the url doesn't exist)
    function get_id($url)
    {
        $q = 'SELECT id FROM '.URL_TABLE.' WHERE (url="'.$url.'")';
        $result = mysql_query('$q');

        if ( mysql_num_rows('$result') )
        {
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            return $row['id'];
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: если хотите писать в стиле ООП,то срочно переходите на php5 или выше , на php 4 слабо развит ООП

Answer (score 2, accepted):

19 строка, это условие а там, функция которая принимает SQL запрос, в данном случае переменную, а у вас переменная в кавычках

> было   **if (
> mysql_num_rows('$result') )**
>
> стало **if (mysql_num_rows($result))**

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь!!! Всё работает, теперь понял свою ошибку! :)))

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_num_rows($result)
```

Без кавычек

Comment: Всё равно не работает. :( Значения подставляются, но только те, что стоят после else, т.е. -1.
P.S. Это сервис сокращения ссылок.

Comment: Странно. Посмотрел на http://sourceforge.net/projects/lilurl/?source=dlp программу. У меня все работает.

Может у вас с базой проблемы?

Comment: Кстати, еще `mysql_query('$q');` без кавычек пишется

Comment: Круть убрал кавычки, вроде заработало! Сейчас ещё потестю и отпишусь! :)

Comment: @Ale_x,
если хотите писать в стиле ООП,то срочно переходите на php5 или выше , на php 4 слабо развит ООП
а как вы определили версию интерпретатора видя только исходный код :-) ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$var = 1;
echo $var, '</br>';
echo '$var';
```

Сравните

Answer (score 0):

как уже сказали - mysql_num_rows($result) - без кавычек, а еще

```
mysql_connect(localhost, LOGIN, PASS) or die('Could not connect to database');
```

пытаетесь соединится с сервером базы, но неправильно куказаны параметры- все должно быть либо в кавычках - если ето реальные значения, либо указана переменная содержащая значение параметра, а также должен быть возвращен идентификатор соединения
ка кто вот так

```
$db=mysql_connect('localhost', $LOGIN, $PASS) or die('Could not connect to database');
```

Comment: Хм странно, но где логин и пароль у меня написаны просто значения из админки, без переменных, и нормально работает. Информация спокойно записывается в БД, корректно, без ошибок.

Comment: а как именно написано?

Comment: mysql_connect(localhost, adminss, dtcmy****) or die('Could not connect to database');

Comment: может у него просто объявлены константы?????!